# Calculate the amount and put the total where the x is not presented in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to make a system where VBA calculates the amount of products and then puts the total end of the X.

Example here:

[image]

Currently, I have this code, but it isn't working:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H1:H150")) Is Nothing Then
        If Not IsEmpty(Target) Then
            Dim TargetPrice, MoveDown As Range
            Set MoveDown = Target
            Set TargetPrice = Target.Offset(, 1)
            Dim TotalPrice As Double
            If Not MoveDown.Value = "x" Then
                TotalPrice = TotalPrice + TargetPrice.Value
            Else
                Do Until IsEmpty(MoveDown.Value) Or Not MoveDown.Value = "x"
                    TotalPrice = TotalPrice + TargetPrice.Value
                    Set TargetPrice = TargetPrice.Offset(1)
                    Set MoveDown = MoveDown.Offset(1)
                Loop
            End If
            Set TargetPrice = TargetPrice.Offset(, 1)
            Range(TargetPrice.Address).Value = TotalPrice
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get these results ...

[image]

from this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim TargetPrice As Range, MoveDown As Range
Dim TargetUnitPrice As Range, Amount As Range
Dim TotalPrice As Double


    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H1:H150")) Is Nothing Then
        Set MoveDown = Target
        ' Capture the case where an "x" is not entered, but there are "x"'s above
        Do Until MoveDown.Offset(-1).Value <> "x"
            Set MoveDown = MoveDown.Offset(-1)
        Loop
        Set TargetUnitPrice = MoveDown.Offset(, 1)
        Set Amount = MoveDown.Offset(, -1)
        If Not IsEmpty(Target) Then
            TotalPrice = 0#
            Do Until IsEmpty(MoveDown.Value) Or Not MoveDown.Value = "x"
                TotalPrice = TotalPrice + (Amount.Value * TargetUnitPrice.Value)
                Set TargetUnitPrice = TargetUnitPrice.Offset(1)
                Set Amount = Amount.Offset(1)
                Set MoveDown = MoveDown.Offset(1)
            Loop
            TotalPrice = TotalPrice + (Amount.Value * TargetUnitPrice.Value)
            Set TargetPrice = MoveDown.Offset(, 2)
            TargetPrice.Value = TotalPrice
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Note: there is a case where someone may enter "m" below a few "x"'s. This will still do the total correctly.

Note: if I interpreted the requirement to multiply the amount by the price incorrectly, then just eliminate all of the Amount references.

I get these results ...

[image]

with this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim TargetPrice As Range, MoveDown As Range
Dim TargetUnitPrice As Range
Dim TotalPrice As Double


    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H1:H150")) Is Nothing Then
        Set MoveDown = Target
        ' Capture the case where an "x" is not entered, but there are "x"'s above
        Do Until MoveDown.Offset(-1).Value <> "x"
            Set MoveDown = MoveDown.Offset(-1)
        Loop
        Set TargetUnitPrice = MoveDown.Offset(, 1)
        If Not IsEmpty(Target) Then
            TotalPrice = 0#
            Do Until IsEmpty(MoveDown.Value) Or Not MoveDown.Value = "x"
                TotalPrice = TotalPrice + TargetUnitPrice.Value
                Set TargetUnitPrice = TargetUnitPrice.Offset(1)
                Set MoveDown = MoveDown.Offset(1)
            Loop
            TotalPrice = TotalPrice + TargetUnitPrice.Value
            Set TargetPrice = MoveDown.Offset(, 2)
            TargetPrice.Value = TotalPrice
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: First one is that what i wanted. I appreciate that :)